# Automatically populate a development or staging environment with scrambled data from a production AWS RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-rds, snapshot, scramble

I use AWS RDS and have 3 environments: development, staging and production (different AWS accounts)
I would like to be able to populate the development and staging environment with the scrambled data from production.
The databases are encrypted, each with their own key.
I use Jenkins (pipelines) to do the automation

What I have so far:

- From Jenkins I can login in to the production AWS.
- There, I determine the latest automatically made snapshot with `aws rds describe-db-snapshots --query="reverse(sort_by(DBSnapshots, &SnapshotCreateTime))[0].DBSnapshotIdentifier`
- I copy that automatically made snapshot: `copy-db-snapshot --source-db-snapshot-identifier ${latestSnapshot} --target-db-snapshot-identifier snapshotToScramble` (since you cannot copy automatically made snapshots)

The next step then would be to share or copy the snapshot with the correct encryption key to the other AWS account, which can than restore the DB from this snapshot.

But I'm kinda stuck on the copy-job: according to AWS: 'Depending on the regions involved and the amount of data to be copied, a cross-region snapshot copy can take hours to complete'. If I create a copy manually, it only shows up after 10 minutes. So I suppose it's not an option to use this strategy: I don't want to let the job wait for 20 minutes, in the hope the copy is done.

I could maybe create an automated job to create a manual copy each night, so that is already available when I start the job, but it seems so ugly and overkill, and I'm still not convinced that the copy-DB with encryption key to another account will work =/

I would rather extract the backup as SQL-queries, but I don't see an option to do that.

Does someone has experience with such setup or knows of a better approach. Is there any standard way of doing this?

Comment: *"I don't want to let the job wait for 20 minutes, in the hope the copy is done."*  The describe-db-snapshots API call could be used in the destination account to poll and wait until the copying snapshot appears in the listing with its status set to `available`.

Comment: Good point! But we host the Jenkins ourselves on a Mac-mini with 2 build executors. I rather not block one of them such long period. Also: the job is ofcourse made to put one of the environments in a clean state. When running sql upgrade scripts, it isn't uncommon that it happens 5 times in a row that we need a clean state. It would be nice if this could run within 3 minutes

Comment: *"I would rather extract the backup as SQL-queries, but I don't see an option to do that."*  RDS doesn't do things for you at that layer, but you can do that, yourself, in exactly the same way you'd do it with a dbms other than RDS... using logical backup ("eyeball-friendly backups made up of SQL statements") tools like mysqldump (MySQL/MariaDB), pg_dump (Postgres), etc.  Which database engine are you running?